# Recreating a webpage by copy-pasting?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I’m new to the world of HTML. I wanted to create a local copy of the website I wanted to play around with by copying, pasting and saving the HTML source, as well as saving the webpage (with all the CSS, javascript, .ico elements etc.) and placing the HTML file in the same directory. However, when I opened up the HTML file, it was broken, and all styles were gone. Why is this so? Sincere apologies if this is a repeat, I didn’t really know what to search when looking for an answer. Thank you!

Comment: Did you download all of the required files?

Comment: HTML links to a lot of other files like external CSS for styling, and images. Those aren't a part of the HTML. If it can't find the needed resources, it will just "do its best" without them.

Comment: Would be helpful knowing the context in which your site is running, like is a static site, does it connect to a database, where are you serving it from or any other clues that may help us assisting you. Consider doing some research and editing the question.

Answer (score 2):

Without going into too much detail - Most modern websites are incredibly complex (JS, CDNs, webfonts, crossdomain content, etc etc) and are unlikely to look like anything reasonable when 'copy and pasted' to a local location.

If you're using Chrome I'd try the `More Tools -> Save Page As` feature which is slightly smarter about preserving dependencies, and even then it might not work very well.

Your best bet is to analyze the site inside of the browser, e.g. Chrome's `Developer Tools` and apply your learnings to a local stack you create from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of impossible to know what's going on without seeing the code or what (if any) errors are being produced by your browser.

I would suggest opening the JavaScript console in your browser to see if there are any errors. I could *guess* that the JS and CSS files are being referenced with an absolute path, and because you're serving them form the filesystem you need a relative path. But like I said, you're just going to have to debug this yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The html file doesn't always contain everything it needs to render the page. Often css is stored in external files.  The html file you copied should have a reference to the css that looks like.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" >
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the stylesheets / scripts in the copied html are pointing to files that don't exist in your copied environment.
Could you post the way you have the files structured?

It could be that you have the filesystem set up differently than in the original webpage, ex/

```
wwwroot/
|-- index.html (which has stylesheet references to "css/styles.css")
|-- app.js
|-- styles.css
```

^ here the index.html file would be looking for styles.css in a folder called "css", but the styles.css file is not in that location.

**(I'm aware this is not an actual answer, and may be more appropriate as a comment. I don't have enough reputation for commenting, so my apologies if I'm not following the StackOverflow ways of doing things.)**

Answer (score 0):

This could be the issue ideally because of the use of the external resources which are being used in that webpage and are not present on your local system.

You can check it from the `developer console` in chrome or whichever browser you are using.

1. Press `F12` while viewing the webpage, this will open the *Developer Tools*
2. Click on the `Console` tab, here you can see all the errors and warnings that can cause any issue to that page.

Refer to the screenshot for the process:
[image]
You will be able to see errors in red color and warnings in orange color.